# Is it possible to place 2 Kubernetes pods in the same network namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

I have this problem where: If I place 2 microservices, in 2 different pod, if I am facing a significant throughput drop compared to the micro-services running on the physical server localhost. But I want to autoscale the microservices independent of each other.

I want the 2 micro-services to be on different pods for scaling but also communicate with each other on localhost to avoid any networking overhead.
I have tried using the netns and IP command but I am not able to figure out how to add the pod on Kubernetes to the network namespace.

If it is possible then how?

Comment: I think it's no possible on your particular scenario, but, you can do something like,  using the sidecar pattern you can have those 2 microservices running in the same pod. If you want to have them living on different pods, then you can use a network policy to ensure just traffic on same namespace. And for autoscaling, you can use a vertical pod autoscaler policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular combination of things you describe isn't possible.

Remember that two Pods aren't necessarily on the same Node, but to share a network namespace they have to be on the same system.  It won't be possible for distinct Pods to share a network namespace.

If they need to share a network namespace, multiple containers in the same Pod will have that effect.  They will be scheduled together on the same Node and they will see each other as `localhost`.  However, they can't be individually addressed – you could have two separate Services, but they'd both target the same Pods – and you won't be able to scale the two components separately.